# Missing return statement } in java error

Tags: java, return

I really can't figure out why my code is causing this error, everything looks correct, thought it keeps coming up as it is missing a return statement }

I tried looking for solutions, and I saw that "while" after "if" is one solution, but since I need multiple numbers I cannot use while, and have to go with "what if"

Could anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.*;

class WS8Q4 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 0;

        System.out.println("Please put in an integer from 0 - 9");
        x = in.nextInt ();

        String answer = numTxt (x);
        System.out.println(answer);
}

public static String numTxt (int x)
    {
        if (x==0)
        {
            return ("Zero");
        }
        else if (x==1)
        {
            return ("One");
        }
        else if (x==2)
        {
            return ("Two");
        }
        else if (x==3)
        {
            return ("Three");
        }
        else if (x==4)
        {
            return ("Four");
        }
        else if (x==5)
        {
            return ("Five");
        }
        else if (x==6)
        {
            return ("Six");
        }
        else if (x==7)
        {
            return ("Seven");
        }
        else if (x==8)
        {
            return ("Eight");
        }
        else if (x==9)
        {
            return ("Nine");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a `switch` block.

Comment: You have to return a value. What do you return if `x == 10`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if `x` is something besides 0-9?  You don't have a return statement for that case.  Add it at the bottom, below your last `else if`:

```
return "Other";
```

Comment: my god that fixed it, thanks ! didn't even notice that, was 99% sure that my code was already correct, but I guess computers never lie !

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a default return statement.

What if , no condition satisfied ?? add an else on the end.

```
else{
  return "not found";
}
```

And you should write

```
return "Zero";
```

There is no need to write         `return ("Zero");`

And your case is perfectly suits for switch case, If you are using >1.6

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of all cases, ie: all the other cases you described in your if-else chain. To fix it, I would throw an exception, indicating that the digit is impossible:

```
public static String numTxt (int x)
{
    String txt[] = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                    "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
    if (0 <= x && x <= 9) return txt[x];
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported digit!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a return in the ending of `public static String numTxt()` method, otherwise what happen if none of your `if` block satisfy?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` with a return statement. If x isn't 0-9, then it doesn't hit any of those return statements. That is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `return` statement at the end of the function.  All of your `return` statements are within `if` branches; the compiler can't be certain that any of them will ever be hit.  You either need a `return` at the very end, or one inside an `else` branch.